# spring aop can't transfer value to customized parameter

Tags: spring-aop

It's a spring boot application,I used aop to catch http head,body.I can do something for @annotation when catch value of http head,body.However,when I tranfer data to my customized parameters,I can't get.but another spring boot application can tranfer it.I don't know why.

this is customized @Aspect:

```java
@Component
@Aspect
public class ApiAspect {
@Resource
private HttpServletRequest request;

@Around("@annotation(com.jvbaoji.api.common.ApiAuth)")
public Object aroundAdvice(ProceedingJoinPoint point) throws Throwable {
    Long userId = Optional.ofNullable(request.getHeader("user_id")).map(Long::valueOf).orElse(null);
    final MethodSignature signature = (MethodSignature) point.getSignature();
    final Method method = signature.getMethod();
    final String methodName = method.getName();
    final Class<?>[] parameterTypes = method.getParameterTypes();
    final Annotation[][] parameterAnnotations;
    parameterAnnotations = point.getTarget().getClass().getMethod(methodName, parameterTypes).getParameterAnnotations();
    final Object[] args = point.getArgs();
    for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
        for (Annotation annotation : parameterAnnotations[i]) {
            if (AuthUserId.class.equals(annotation.annotationType())) {
                args[i] = userId;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return point.proceed();
}
}
```

customized @interface:

```java
@Target({ElementType.METHOD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface ApiAuth {
}
```

parameter:

```java
@Target({ElementType.PARAMETER})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface AuthUserId {
}
```

controller:

```java
@RequestMapping(value = "updateAccount", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ApiAuth
public JsonNode updateAccount(@AuthUserId Long userId, @ModelAttribute UserAccountVO userAccountVO) {
    userAccountVO.setUserId(userId);
    TransmissionResult result = userWalletService.updateAccount(userAccountVO);
    if (!result.isSuccess()) {
        return responseJsonFactory.createBad(result.getCode(), result.getFailReason());
    }
    return responseJsonFactory.createOk(jsonMapper.convertValue(userAccountVO, JsonNode.class));
}
```

I found when I post http, I can debug to `arg[i]=userId`,but to return `point.proceed()`,it throws a NullException.My `@AuthUserId Long userId` can't get return value.I dont know why.

ps:My spring aop version is spring-aop-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar in spring boot.

Thanks whatever advice If you give.

Comment: Just so as to understand you correctly before answering: a) You are aware of the fact that the aspect is a singleton and thus the injected request will always be the same? b) From what I see, my impression is that the aspect's purpose is to hack user authorisation. If so, I hope you have legal reasons to do so. Can you please comment on that briefly?

Comment: NoNoNo.It's my application,I don't know how to hack user authorisation.I just get userId in my applicaton for my project.however I still get none.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK,It's my ignorance...I missed to add args to proceed.

In ApiAspect.class:

```
return point.proceed();
```

to

```
return point.proceed(args);
```